# Distance from gas pipe/meter to outdoor junction box in code

Tags: electrical

I know that an outlet should be 3' from the gas. Given a junction box on the outside of my house that is less that 3' away, can I take out the outlets and run conduit from it over to a new box and satisfy code (with the new box well more than 3' away from the gas pipe)?